# Matrix multiplication definition / intuition

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a textbook which defines matrix-vector multiplication as follows:

Let $\mathbf A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix. Let $\mathbf x$ be an $n$-column vector. Then $\mathbf A\mathbf x$ is defined as follows:

- If $m=1$ then $\mathbf A\mathbf x$ is the scalar $a_{11} x_{1}+a_{12} x_{2}+\ldots+a_{1n}x_{n}=\mathbf a_{1}\cdot\mathbf x$
- If $m>1$ then $\mathbf A\mathbf x$ is the $m$-column vector whose rows are the dot products (as above) of the $m$th row of $\mathbf A$ with $\mathbf x$

It then defines matrix multiplication in terms of matrix-vector multiplication. The argument (this is my wording, so this is as best I understand it) goes as follows. Let's call it argument (I):

1. Let $\mathbf A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and let $\mathbf B$ be an
   $n \times s$ matrix.
2. $\mathbf A$ can be thought of as a column of its row vectors $\mathbf a_{i}$:

$\mathbf A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots& \vdots \\
a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \cdots & a_{mn} \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf a_{1}\\\mathbf a_{2}\\\vdots\\\mathbf a_{m}\end{bmatrix}$

3. $\mathbf B$ can be thought of as a row of its column vectors $\mathbf b^{j}$:

$\mathbf B=
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} & \cdots & b_{1s} \\
b_{21} & b_{22} & \cdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots& \vdots \\
b_{n1} & b_{n2} & \cdots & b_{ns} \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf b^{1}&\mathbf b^{2}&\cdots&\mathbf b^{s}\end{bmatrix}$

4. Then $\mathbf A\mathbf B$ can be thought of as doing matrix-vector multiplication repeatedly, column-wise, for the $\mathbf A\mathbf b^{j}$, giving a row vector with components $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf A\mathbf b^{1}&\mathbf A\mathbf b^{2}&\cdots&\mathbf A\mathbf b^{s}\end{bmatrix}$.
5. Expanding the components of the $\mathbf A\mathbf b^{j}$ back out again using the matrix-vector definition above results in the $m \times s$ matrix you would expect:

$\mathbf A\mathbf B=
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf a_{1}\cdot\mathbf b^{1} & \mathbf a_{1}\cdot\mathbf b^{2} & \cdots & \mathbf a_{1}\cdot\mathbf b^{s} \\
\mathbf a_{2}\cdot\mathbf b^{1} & \mathbf a_{2}\cdot\mathbf b^{2} & \cdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots& \vdots \\
\mathbf a_{m}\cdot\mathbf b^{1} & \mathbf a_{m}\cdot\mathbf b^{2} & \cdots & \mathbf a_{m}\cdot\mathbf b^{s} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

Argued this way, this seems okay. But my question is: in steps (2) and (3) of argument (I), couldn't you equally have considered $\mathbf A$ to be a row of its column vectors, and $\mathbf B$ to be a column of its row vectors? In which case, $\mathbf A\mathbf B$ would be a $1 \times 1$ matrix (i.e. a scalar), instead of an $m \times s$ matrix, right?

So are steps 2 and 3 just a definition, rather than an intuition?

In general, when I re-interpret matrices from being 2-D arrays of scalars, to columns of row vectors, to rows of column vectors, to 2-D arrays of block matrices, am I supposed to get all the same results under any of these points of view, or can I get different results, depending on my perspective?

Comment: You were almost right. If $A$ is a row (of columns $a_i$), and $B$ is a column (of rows $b_i$), then indeed $AB$ has only one "element" of the form $\sum_i a_i b_i$, but now each $a_i$ is a column $m\times 1$, and each $b_i$ is a row $1\times s$, so by your rule, each $a_i b_i$ is actually a $m\times s$ matrix

Comment: Ohh thanks, that's really helpful! I guess each $a_{i}b_{i}$ would have lots of zeroes in it (prior to summing them all)?

Comment: Actually not. Only if $a_i$ or $b_i$ have some zeros. For example, if they are the all-ones vectors, then $a_ib_i$ is the all-ones matrix